# RTSP DESCRIBE fails with "401 Unauthorized" only in PyCharm

Tags: python, rtsp

I am currently attempting to stream video in order to implement face recognition. However, I am encountering issues with the RTSP protocol in PyCharm. I have used an RTSP link that was successfully tested with VLC player, but when I attempt to use the same link in PyCharm, it does not function as expected.

My program:

```
import cv2
import time

# RTSP URL of the stream
rtsp_url = "rtsp://********:*******@***.***.***.***:***"

# Create a VideoCapture object
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_url)

# Check if the camera opened successfully
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Unable to open RTSP stream.")
    exit()

# Maximum number of retries
  max_retries = 3
  retry_count = 0

# Read frames from the stream
while True:
    # Read a frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

# Check if the frame was read successfully
if ret:
    # Frame was successfully read, do something with it
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
else:
    # Frame read failed, increment retry count
    retry_count += 1
    print(f"Failed to read frame. Retry count: {retry_count}/{max_retries}")

    # Check if maximum number of retries reached
    if retry_count >= max_retries:
        print("Maximum number of retries reached. Exiting.")
        break

# Exit if 'q' is pressed
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

# Add a delay before retrying
time.sleep(1)

# Release the VideoCapture object and close all windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I got this Error:

```
pydev debugger: process 17812 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 201.8538.36)
Error: Unable to open RTSP stream.
[rtsp @ 000001b3c7b02840] method DESCRIBE failed: 401 Unauthorized
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you enter username , password?

Comment: Does it work in console Like python your_script.py i think its not pycharm releated. Vlc is Not opencv vlc is way more flexible. 401 is an authentication Error. Try to disable auth and retest. Than U Know whats Produce This error